# React & Jest: Cannot find module from test file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jestjs

Setting up a Jest test ('App-test.js') for a Redux action ('App.js') in a directory `app/__tests__`:

Here's the header of App.js:

```
jest.unmock('../../modules/actions/App.js')

import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils'

import * as App from '../../modules/actions/App.js'
```

In `app/` there is a module `config.js`. This is being imported where it is needed.

The problem is, when I run my Jest tests, such as App-test.js, it is looking for config and not finding it:

```
 FAIL  __tests__/actions/App-test.js
Runtime Error
Error: Cannot find module 'config' from 'User.js'
```

And `User.js` is importing `config` like so:
`import config from 'config'`

`User.js` is another action being used `App.js`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Post some more code, kinda confusing without more code to see what needs fixing. Could be issue with how you're using `export`.

Comment: Maybe it's typo but I'm not sure... Try adding ./ to the config path, so it will be import config from './config'; Maybe jest is trying to reach package named config in node_modules?

I don't know what version of jest are you using but automocking is disabled since v15.0.0 - https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#jest-1500

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the module location, otherwise Node.js will try to guess the location for you, like:

```
node_modules/config.js
node_modules/config/index.js
node_modules/config/package.json
```

The problem in your code is the assumption that node will look for the file in the desired location, as you can see in the algorithm I provided in the previous lines.

To fix the issue you have to specify the location inside your User.js file, for example, check the hypothetical file organization:

```
/
/config.js
/app
/app/User.js
```

Then, you'd import inside User.js:

```
import config from '../config.js'
```

The file `config.js` is relative to User.js, located in the parent directory.