# Jest/Enzyme and Styled Components Cannot find module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, styled-components

I am getting the following error when I run

```
npm run test

src/components/documentEditor/levels/2_page/page.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'react' from 'styled-components.cjs.js'

    However, Jest was able to find:
        './page.js'
        './page.test.js'

    You might want to include a file extension in your import, or update your 'moduleFileExtensions', which is currently ['web.js', 'js', 'web.ts', 'ts', 'web.tsx', 'tsx', 'json', 'web.jsx', 'jsx', 'node'].

    See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulefileextensions-array-string
```

The   {Cannot find module 'react' from 'styled-components.cjs.js'} error I think refers to the import in the 'Page' component that is being tested

the 'Page' component runs perfectly if I do not run any testing and the styledComponents is used and works.

The header of the 'Page' component looks like this (not the full component just the first few lines)

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Droppable, Draggable } from 'react-beautiful-dnd';
import { filterArrayByChildrenIds } from '../../functions/supportingFunctions/generic';
import ModifyPage from './modifyPage';
import Paragraph from '../3_paragraph/paragraph';

const Container = styled.div``;
const Title = styled.div``;
const VerticalList = styled.div`
```

The Jest setup in package.JSON is this

```
 {
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.3",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.3",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.3.0",
    "uuid": "^3.3.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/components/documentEditor/*.js",
      "!<rootDir>/node_modules/",
      "!<rootDir>/src/index.js",
      "!<rootDir>/src/registerServiceWorker.js"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
}
```

**WHAT I INVESTIGATED**

1. Similar issues seem to point to the import statement being too general. I found this post
   [React & Jest: Cannot find module from test file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37307799/react-jest-cannot-find-module-from-test-file). However I could not figure out if I was specifically doing something wrong from the post.
2. I also thought it might might be some incompatibility between jest or enzyme and the styled library but could not find anything on it.
3. I found this on stack overflow but doesn't seem to be the same problem [Testing component created using styled component with jest and enzyme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59503501/testing-component-created-using-styled-component-with-jest-and-enzyme).
4. I removed import styled from 'styled-components' from page.js and all references to styled components. After completing that I got a new error

```
  src/components/documentEditor/levels/2_page/page.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'react' from 'react-beautiful-dnd.cjs.js'

    However, Jest was able to find:
        './page.js'
        './page.test.js'
```

Answer (score 1):

**FIX** 
I navigated to the client directory and installed react-beautiful and styled there (as they were installed but in the server directory and when I ran jset from the client directory they were not loaded).

**WHY DID THIS WORK?**
The app is node (server) and react (client) meaning there are two node module directories and two package.json files

When I run the app I usually run it from the server which runs  the module "concurrently" and then runs the client.

react-beautiful and styled-components were installed into the node directory of the server - they then were loaded when I ran the app.

I was running Jest from the client directory meaning the server and node modules were not being loaded